# Embedded YouTube Video won't play with ?autoplay=1

Tags: youtube

Any thoughts on why the embedded YouTube video won't autoplay on this site?

https://quantumleapin.wpengine.com/

As far as I can tell the autoplay is integrated correctly…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `src` attribute is not formatted correctly, it reads :

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/T8u41Uy7wNw?rel=0&showinfo=0?ecver=1?autoplay=1
```

It should be :

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/T8u41Uy7wNw?rel=0&showinfo=0&ecver=1&autoplay=1
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Such a silly mistake on my part. I appreciate your time looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing was happening to me and I copied the embed code exactly from YouTube and it included that `?ecver=1` which was making it not play. Once I removed `?ecver=1`  it was ok.